# Which HTML format is semantically correct?

Tags: html, format, semantics, semantic-markup

I want to know which is the correct / best HTML format?

freeCodeCamp suggests the second format, but when I run that format through an HTML validator, it gives me errors.

**1:**

```
<section id="Hello_world" class="main-section">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
    <p>To get started with writing JavaScript, open the Scratchpad and write your first "Hello world" JavaScript code:</p>
      <code>
         function greetMe(yourName) { alert("Hello " + yourName); }
         <br>
         greetMe("World");
      </code>
</section>
```

OR

**2:**

```
<section id="Hello_world" class="main-section">
  <header>Hello world</header>
<article>
    <p>To get started with writing JavaScript, open the Scratchpad and write your first "Hello world" JavaScript code:</p>
      <code>
         function greetMe(yourName) { alert("Hello " + yourName); }
         <br>
         greetMe("World");
      </code>
</article>
</section>
```

I'm confused as I thought the first format was correct but freeCodeCamp is suggesting otherwise. Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To write multiple lines of pre-formatted code, you should use a `<code>` element inside a `<pre>` element, without the `<br>` element.

Additionally, it may be better to use an `<article>` instead of a `<section>`, since the content reads like it's redistributable—but without more context it's hard to tell.

If "Hello World" is the title of the article, you should use a `<h1>` instead of a `<header>`. The `<header>` element is a sectioning element, not a typographic element.

Putting this all together, I'd take an approach like this:

```css
pre {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<article id="hello-world" class="main-section">
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
  <p>To get started with writing JavaScript, open the Scratchpad and write your first "Hello world" JavaScript code:</p>
  <pre><code>function greetMe(yourName) {
  alert("Hello " + yourName);
}

greetMe("World");</code></pre>
</article>
```

**Additional Notes:**

Be sure you're using an HTML5 validator. If you try to validate HTML5 code with a validator that only works for previous versions of HTML, you'll get a lot of errors.

FreeCodeCamp is incorrect in this case. The best place I've found for learning HTML semantics is reading through the MDN Web Docs' [HTML Element Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element).

Comment: https://karinapichardo.github.io/Technical-Documentation-Page/ , this is the website I built, do you still agree that <article> is better suited?

Comment: `<section>` seems more appropriate in this context

Comment: Okay cool! see freeCodeCamp used <section> and then an <article> tag as well, I guess I need more practice using both.

Comment: Also, in this context, all of those h1's should be h2's, except for "JS Documentation" @karinapichardo

Comment: Great! I just updated that, thanks for everything!!